# How to change the axis title font size of a `trellis` object?

Tags: r, fonts, lattice, axis-labels, trellis

I have a `trellis` object generated by a 3rd-party package. With that being said, I cannot change the attributes by re-creating another `trellis` object. I have to change its attributes *after* it has been created.

I have figured out which attributes control the axes' **label** font sizes, they are:
`my_trellis$x.scales$cex[1]` and `my_trellis$y.scales$cex[1]`

But what about the axes' **title** font sizes? It took me some searches and still could not figure it out...

Thanks!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: One possible guess: if you wanted to make all text/labels bigger, try `my_trellis$par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=22))`

Comment: @MrFlick Your suggestion can be a workaround, thank you! But it changes both text and label at the same time... Just then I was trying to `dput` my `trellis` for your investigation but when re-run it returns the error `'...' used in an incorrect context` and I can yet figure out how...

Answer (score 1):

You can change `trellis` object of `lattice` package by using `trellis.par.get` and `trellis.par.set` function as below:

```
library(lattice)
# simulation
data("quakes")
Depth <- equal.count(quakes$depth, number=8, overlap=.1)
trellis <- xyplot(lat ~ long | Depth, data = quakes, main = "Large Font Title")


# change title font size
mt = trellis.par.get("par.main.text")
mt$cex = 2
trellis.par.set("par.main.text",mt)
trellis
class(trellis)
```

Output:
[image: library]